# Passengers with baby asked to move across the aisle

Tags: air-travel, india, domestic-travel

While travelling a domestic flight in India we (my wife and I) were seated on seats 7E and 7F (3-3 configuration) and the rest of the seats in the row were occupied by a family who had a baby which was with someone seated in 7B

The air hostess said that the baby could not be present at the side and requested us to switch seats such that we were now seated on 7A and 7B, and the baby on 7E.

We did not get a chance to ask what the reason for this was. What could have been the reason for the baby not being permitted on one side of the aisle?

---

Flight Details:

Aircraft : Airbus A320-232
Tail Number : VT-IFY
Flying from Bangalore (BLR) to Indore (IDR)
Flight: https://www.flightradar24.com/data/aircraft/vt-ify#24002f91

Comment: It is possibly something regarding the specific airplane that was in use. What was the flight number and date?

Comment: Often they also move parents/baby to aisles with extra leg space, and/or put them at front both for the leg space and to minimize the people around it...

Answer (score 88, accepted):

It's impossible to say for certain without know the plane involved, but...

All commercial passenger aircraft must have at least one emergency oxygen mask for each passenger.

For the most part this is a simple calculation - 3 seats on each side of the aisle means 3 oxygen masks for each group of seats.  However this obviously doesn't take into account any passengers that do not have their own seats - such as lap babies!

In order to handle this, aircraft have additional masks available, but these may not be available at all seats.  For many models of aircraft, all of the seats along one side of the plane will have an extra mask available, whilst those on the other side will not.

It sounds like on the plane you were on, the seats on the A-B-C side of the aircraft only had 3 masks, whilst those on the D-E-F side had 4. As a result, the passengers with the baby had to move to the side with the extra mask.

(Note that technically it's not just the model - different airlines will order different configs, which can include things like this.  So on one airline the extra masks might be on one side, on another airline on the other, and on a third airline they could have paid extra to have 4 masks on both sides!)

Comment: I'm surprised the airplane doesn't tip over with all that extra weight on one side! /s

Comment: @JMac that's why they put the extra masks at the aisle instead of the window - less imbalance to trim out!
/s

Comment: I imagine this would be a real problem for a couple travelling with *two* babies.  They'd have to split the parents up onto different rows so that each gets one child.  Don't even want to think about what's required for people with even larger families like the Octomom et al.  (I'm guessing you just *don't* fly until the kids are old enough to get their own seats.)

Comment: @DarrelHoffman Children over 2 years need their own seats.  I suspect the answer is for the family to buy seated tickets for all but the {# of adults in party} smallest children.  I travelled with a 1 year old.  I found the seats to be extremely cramped and my 1 year old ate a full sized airplane meal and then some of mine.

Comment: @emory Yeah, it's probably mostly only a problem for people with twins/triplets/etc., because otherwise it's pretty much impossible that more than 2 kids would be under the minimum age.  Barring adoption or more other unusual circumstances I guess.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman It is definitely true in my experience that if you are traveling with two lap babies the family must be split into 2 rows to accommodate the number of masks.

Comment: @DarrelHoffman it is also seen when multiple parties travel with kids (e.g., I want to sit on 18A with my kid, you want to sit on 18B with your kid, and other guy wants to sit on 18C with their kid).  One would hope that modern ticketing systems would prevent that, but I am less than confident.

Comment: @emory The airlines systems for most (all?) airline WILL handle that - as long as the lap child is listed on the reservation.  In some countries they don't need to be, which is likely what led to the initial issue this question was about

Comment: @DarrelHoffman My wife and I were in this exact scenario once.  We have two 19 months apart, and flew one flight where they were both under 2.  We were indeed required to not sit in the same group of seats, as (similar 3-3 configuration) there were only 4 masks.

Comment: @Doc my experience was in the US with a 1 year old.  I bought tickets online 1 for me and a "lap ticket" for my 1 year old.  There were problems checking in.  The online system had correctly collected the $0 fare for the "lap ticket" but had neglected to collect the taxes.  It took them 30 minutes to figure this out.  Given that, I have no confidence in the airline ticketing systems.